# Needs to update the image id extract from the submitted image?

Tags: php

i just need help ..

i am working on Image library where admin can upload multiple images with single category id. The images are in this format like "ABC_12345_business","ABC_23567_business" etc. i have successfully upload the multiple images to a single category. but  i want when i click submit button the images will insert into the database along with update the image id[e.g 12345,23567] in a separate row. so that it will easy for me to search the image by image id.

can you pls explain me how to do it???

Answer (score 0):

Process each image something like this:

```
$fileName = 'ABC_123456_bussiness';
$fileParts = explode('_', $fileName);
#Fileparts contains now:
#$fileParts[0] = 'ABC';
#$fileParts[1] = '123456';
#$fileParts[2] = 'bussiness';
insertIntoDB($fileParts);
```

Is this something what you where looking for?

Comment: but here i am uploading multiple images to a single category.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I'm not really sure what you're looking for:

But if you want to do it dynamically you could do a AJAX request with help of the javascript-library jQuery for example.

But if I'm going to proceed from Holger's track I would do the explosion in the function AND instead do i t like this:

```
 function insertIntoDb(&$fileName){
  list($name, $id, $category) = explode("_",$fileName);
  //do shit here
}
```